# How to `git reset` non-recursively with git's pathspec globbing?

Tags: bash, git, glob

I'm trying to run a `git reset` on each commit, as part of a `git index-filter` query:

`$ git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached -qr --ignore-unmatch -- . && git reset -q $GIT_COMMIT -- *.xml' --prune-empty -- --all`

However, because the `git reset` is within single quotes, the `*` is not subjected to Bash's shell globbing; it's being handled by git's pathspec rules instead.

This isn't working well because I can't find a way to tell `git reset` to only reset the files in the repository root.

Consider the following sample git repo:

```
.git/
a.xml
q.xml
directory1/b.xml
directory2/directory3/filename.txt
```

Desired: only `a.xml` and `q.xml` should be reset

Observed: `a.xml`, `q.xml`, and `directory1/b.xml` are **all** getting reset.

I've tried the following:

- `git reset '/*.xml'` -- this fails because it's trying to `git reset` against the directory `/`, which obviously isn't inside my git repository
- `git reset './*.xml'` -- surprisingly, this resets `b.xml` as well
- `git reset '$(find * -type f -maxdepth 1)'` -- the `$()` is not recognised by `git reset`, and of course git doesn't pass it to Bash to handle it, so this fails with an error message
- `git reset a.xml q.xml` -- this works *okay*, but, it assumes that those are the only two XML files in the repository root across *all past revisions* of my project (seeing as `index-filter` is running against every past revision). So it sort-of works, but not *correctly*.

So, is there a valid `git reset` pathspec that will actually work here?

Alternatively, can I rewrite my command to avoid the single quotes, so that Bash can interpret the globs? (Pretty sure this would be inappropriate because it'd only be applying against the current files in the latest revision of the repo, not the ones that existed in past states.)

Maybe I should literally be invoking `bash` from inside the single quotes?

Comment: Actually, bash *is* expanding the `*` as the entire string is fed to `eval`. You would have to add one more level of quoting to pass the `*` to Git so that Git can expand `*.xml`. But in this particular case, `*.xml` probably does not match any files, in which case the expanded text is just `*.xml`. If it does match some file(s), that would introduce a problem. (I don't remember offhand whether `--index-filter` runs in a filter-branch temporary directory.)

Answer (score 0):

As you've pointed out `*` doesn't expand under quotes and you just have to move it out of the quotes. Or a better way to use the array and put the glob results and pass it to the command.

```
shopt -s nullglob
xmlFiles=(*.xml)
```

By default `*.xml` does not undergo recursive globbing, one needs to set a special option i.e. `globstar` to achieve that. For your case though, you can confirm only the `.xml` files under the current folder which would have been globbed

```
echo '*.xml expands to '"${xmlFiles[@]}"''
```

So now using the array in your `git` command.

```
git filter-branch --index-filter \
     'git rm --cached -qr --ignore-unmatch -- . && git reset -q $GIT_COMMIT -- '"${xmlFiles[@]}"'' --prune-empty -- --all
```